# Strange behavior with Spring Data MongoDb and index on abstract class

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I have a parent class Task where I create multiple compound indexes.

```
@Document
@CompoundIndexes({
        @CompoundIndex(def = "{'contract': 1, 'executionAt': 1}"),
        @CompoundIndex(def = "{'contract': 1, 'name': 1}")
})
public abstract class Task {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    @Indexed
    private Contract contract;

    private String name;

    private Instant executionAt;
}
```

After that I extend this class.

```
public static class LaunchNoMoveTask extends Task {

        public static final String TASK_NAME = LaunchNoMoveTask.class.getSimpleName();

        private Instant lastMove;

        private Room room;

        private Duration threshold;
}
```

I want to save all tasks on a single collection. Before, compound indexes creation there was no problem. There was only one collection. But now, I have 1 collection by task. Those collections seems always empty and I can see compound indexes specified on Task class on each collection.

What should I do to have a compound indexes on Task and only 1 collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put a collection name in the document annotation on the abstract class which will be given to all children.

```
@Document(name = "task")
@CompoundIndexes({
        @CompoundIndex(def = "{'contract': 1, 'executionAt': 1}"),
        @CompoundIndex(def = "{'contract': 1, 'name': 1}")
})
public abstract class Task {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    @Indexed
    private Contract contract;

    private String name;

    private Instant executionAt;
}
```